# ARM Get ASB ConnectionString into Key Vault

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I am trying to grab a connection string from a service bus namespace and inject it into key vault via ARM. Basically have:

- KeyVault lives in `ResourceGroup1`
- ASB Namespace lives in `ResourceGroup2`

I am trying to use ARM to grab the primary connection string and add it to key vault using:

```
{
  "name": "[concat(parameters('keyVaultName'), '/MyListenConnectionString')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
  "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "properties": {
    "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules','sb-namespace','listen-key'),'2015-08-01').primaryConnectionString]"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[parameters('keyVaultName')]"
  ]
}
```

It doesn't seem to like this. Have I got to do something special because the two resources live under different resource groups?

The error I get:

```
##vso[task.issue type=error;]ParentResourceNotFound: Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'sb-namespace' not found.
```

I am assuming because they live in two different resource groups?

Comment: COuld you please if your azure service namespace has existed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your service bus namespace and Azure key vault are in the different resource group, you need to define the function as below. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource?tabs=json#remarks-3).

```
listKeys(resourceId('<group name>','Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules','sb-namespace','listen-key'),'2015-08-01').primaryConnectionString
```

For example

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    ...
  },
  "resources": [
    ...
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "proxyKey": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('0730BowmanWindow','Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules',parameters('sbName'),parameters('ruleName')'),'2015-08-01').primaryConnectionString]"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]